# How to use method on multiple variables on one line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, methods, settext

How can i do this:

```
[wage setText:@""];
[hours setText:@""];
[grossPay setText:@""];
[taxes setText:@""];
[netPay setText:@""];
```

in one line?

Comment: wage.text = hours.text = grossPay.text = taxes.text = netPay.text = @"";

Comment: The easiest way would be to remove the new line characters :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it in one line.  Do it so that it's easy to understand.  To quote Brian Kernighan:

> Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?

Answer (score 2):

If all of these are KVC compliant and you want to put the same value, you could put all of these in an array then set the text.

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:wage, hours, grossPay, taxes, netPay, nil] setValue:@"" forKey:@"text"];
```

Or hoshi's idea is good too.  (again it requires KVC compliance)

A non KVC solution :

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:wage, hours, grossPay, taxes, netPay, nil] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a model class,as:

```
@interface DbInfos : NSObject{
    NSString *wage;
    NSString *hours;
    NSString *grossPay;
    NSString *taxes;
    NSString *netPay;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *wage;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *hours;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *grossPay;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *taxes;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *netPay;

-(id)initWithWage:(NSString *)newWage Hours:(NSString *)newHours GrossPay:(NSString *)newTaxes NetPay:(NSString *)newNetPay;
```

Answer (score 0):

agreeing with Rob (+1) on this one, but answering for *fun*:

```
for (UILabel * at in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:wage, hours, grossPay, taxes, netPay, nil]) at.text = @"";
```

note that this would fail if `wage`, `hours`, `grossPay`, or `taxes` were `nil`.